# Is there a best way to manually disable and re-enable a binded button?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In my ViewModel I have the following method:

```
public async Task<Boolean> DoSomething(Button sender)
{
    Binding binding = sender.GetBindingExpression(Button.IsEnabledProperty).ParentBinding;

    sender.IsEnabled = false;

    DoFastStuffs();

    await Task.Delay(250);

    sender.SetBinding(Button.IsEnabledProperty, binding);

    return true;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Because I noticed that setting the property manually without saving the binding somewhere removes the actual binding from the XAML object forever.

EDIT: here is my button:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToBooleanConverter}, ElementName=ComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Comment: If you have a property (`Button.IsEnabled`) bound to a source property (presumably on your VM), then why don't you just change the source property? If you have bound the button to an `ICommand`, then you'd change the return value of `CanExecute` and raise `CanExecuteChanged`.

Comment: Manipulating the Binding in the VM (almost) always is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: The problem is that IsEnabled property is binded to the SelectedItem of a ComboBox. Then there is no item selected, the button is disabled and vice-versa. Should I really create a Multiconverter and another notification property to temporary disable a button?

Comment: Is your `Button` bound to a `Command`? If so, the right way to do this would probably be to use the command's `CanExecute()` to return `false` if either the `SelectedItem` is `null` or if `IsLoading=true`

Comment: a viewmodel in term of MVVM does not contain a referenc to the view(button in your case) - so please dont call it ViewModel. to your question, check Commanding with MVVM (RelayCommand or DelegateCommand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not bind the Command property of your button.  Implementing ICommand will also give you the enable/disable operations on the UI control for (almost) free using the CanExecute() functionality to check your ComboBox's selected item...

Comment: ICommand documentation is here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx